# Hide EXPORT button in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way to hide the Export button in SQL Server Reporting Services (Webportal)? I managed to disable all the rendering options, i.e. PDF, Excel, Word, etc., so that there is no selection possible, but the button itself is still visible. I have done this once in the past, but can't remember how. Is there a .css file that I need to change?